# How to populate data into html in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to populate data into the html page using Angular framework.

I want to add data to existing accordion element

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<accordion id='accordion' close-others="false">
    <accordion-group is-open="false">
        <accordion-heading >
            <h2>{{heading}}</h2>
        </accordion-heading>
            <div>
                <div>
                    {{data}}
                </div>
            </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>

<accordion>
 ....more
</accordion>
multiple accordions here...

</div>
```

I am not sure how to add more accordion dynamically. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this using AngularUI? If not, that will definitely help.

Comment: yes this is angular ui

Comment: So you want to be able to create more accordions dynamically? I would wrap this in a directive, use the html you have as the template, and set scope: {header: '=', data: '='}. Then you could create as many accordions as you want just by creating your custom directive element and giving it the data.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Could you please give an example? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of trick you can do, like using ng-show or ng-hide for example, and have all the accordion all ready write on the page, or a ng-repaet with various accordion inside, but take care of the space in the page.
If i Have understand your problem you can set a variable in that way `var data={value:'something',show:'true'}` and bind the ng-show parameter to the data show, at least you can do an array of data with the show value, there is an infinite type of solution.
With a plunker or a fiddle it could be easier to help, but i hope my answer could help you anyway.